# How to create link on file in Atom?

Tags: markdown

Trying use this:

```
[FILE](dir/file.md)
```

or this

```
[FILE](file://dir/file.md)
```

But it dosent work

Comment: Hi Welcome to stackoverflow, Maybe add some context as to what you're trying to do and what problem you're facing

Comment: This discussion from atom.io suggests using `markdown-preview-enhanced`: https://discuss.atom.io/t/markdown-preview-follow-a-link-from-one-md-file-to-another/35886

Comment: `markdown-preview-enhanced` is work! Thank you very match!